# How do I know whether my computer is compatible with Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, installation

Is there even a reason why I should be asking this question? I'm sure it would run but just in case I want to know if it's perfectly safe for me to assume that all hardware drivers will be supported? I have a good laptop that's running Windows 7 RC 7100 32-bit and have my MAPS Win7 Pro 64-bit DVD handy with me... and fidgeting...!

Comment: What is the laptop manufacturer and model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx)** will tell you with certainty whether your computer meets the requirements for Windows 7 x86 or x64.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to post the CPU information and we can tell you!

Press <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> then look where it says Processor.

Google that information or look on either [Intel](http://www.intel.com) or on [AMD](http://www.amd.com) for the CPU and see if it is compatible. That being said, nearly every mainstream (and some budget) CPUs in the last couple of years have been 64 bit.

Comment: Wil, thanks, it's a superb processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T9300 @2.5GHz - think this should be compatible!

Comment: I can tell you 100% that it is compatible, it is what I use for Windows 7 x64!

Answer (score 1):

There is a free utility called [Securable](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) that reports the maximum bit length, as well as some other features of the processor it is run on. If this reports 64 bits, you should be good to go.